# How to redirect back to the same page using PrettyFaces?

Tags: java, jsf, prettyfaces

I'd like to know how to redirect to the same page on action call.

I have this commandButton:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{someBean.edit}" value="Edit" />
```

This is the action:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class SomeBean {

    public String edit() {
        // some logic
        return "theSamePage?faces-redirect=true";
    }

}
```

But it doesn't redirect to the same page, it just refreshes it so when I try to refresh the page by pressing F5 key, the duplicate submission occurs. This can be solved, under normal circumstances, with post/redirect/get. But faces won't send the redirect when the action method returns the same viewId as the viewId of the page that the request is send from.

I use prettyfaces.

Comment: Please update your question. Based on my deleted answer you're using PrettyFaces, but this important detail is missing in the question.

Comment: I don't think it's relevant, but I updated it anyway.

Comment: It's definitely relevant. The standard JSF solution didn't work for you.

Comment: I guess you are right. I tried to disable prettyfaces and it worked. I guess it's a prettyfaces bug.

Comment: If this is a bug in PrettyFaces, please report it in our issue tracker. Thanks! https://github.com/ocpsoft/prettyfaces/issues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
return "pretty:";
```

Is pretty much what you need.

Comment: Thanks bro! You've saved my day big time.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some searching and rewriting my answer:

The view id in pretty faces you can get by doing this:

```
      PrettyContext prettyContext = PrettyContext.newInstance((HttpServletRequest) request); 
      String viewId = prettyContext.getCurrentCalculatedViewId();
```

Check this for more information: https://groups.google.com/group/prettyfaces-users/browse_thread/thread/f50482709d7ec69b?pli=1

Comment: This isn't exactly what the OP is asking. The OP needs a redirect to the same view, not a forward to an arbitrary view.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work, the double post problem still occurs.